# How to mask outbound URL in ASP.NET MVC?

Tags: asp.net, wordpress, azure, url-routing

I'm trying to redirect and mask all users from a page at my ASP.NET website to another website not using ASP.NET.  ie, from www.site.com/site2 to www.site2.com.  I want the url to be masked, so that users see www.site.com/site2 in their url rather than www.site2.com, and for subpages like site.com/site2/home to also work.  My website is hosted on Microsoft Azure, and I would ideally like to redirect to a completely different page, but could also redirect to another Azure page.

However, I've been getting a bit confused with terminology.  What methods can I use to go about this, and is there a specific search term I should be using?  There are a lot of resources that discuss doing the opposite (masking part of your website as another site), but fewer masking an outward site as part of your site.

So far, I've found a couple of possible methods - Virtual Directories, and URL Rewrite.
For Virtual Directories, I found this useful blogpost: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/kaushal/archive/2014/04/19/microsoft-azure-web-sites-deploying-wordpress-to-a-virtual-directory-within-the-azure-web-site.aspx

But it doesn't quite work and I'm finding it difficult to find any more resources about Virtual Directories.

I also found URL Rewrite, which looks pretty cool: [Mask URL to subdomain using IIS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20599307/mask-url-to-subdomain-using-iis)

However, they also mention that URL rewrite only works on the same website, which is not the case here.

Will either of these work to mask site2.com as site.com/site2?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was not able to do exactly what I wanted to - simply redirect traffic from site.com/site2 to site2.com (and let users see site.com/site2 in the url).  URL Rewrite does not do this, but it does do the opposite (map server content at site.com/site2 to user sees site2.com).

Virtual directories are close enough though.  I'm actually storing the content at site.com/site2, so users see that as the URL. If I want users to alternately see site2.com if they go there, I can use URL Rewrite.

The first blog post I linked (http://blogs.msdn.com/b/kaushal/archive/2014/04/19/microsoft-azure-web-sites-deploying-wordpress-to-a-virtual-directory-within-the-azure-web-site.aspx) actually is spot on with how to set up Virtual Directories.

One of the problems for me following that post was the Site name and destination URL of the publish settings.
[image: Azure Virtual Directory Settings]
[image: Visual Studio/WebMatrix Publish Settings]

Basically the extension from Azure (outlined in red) matches the URL from publish settings, while the site\wwwroot\wordpress from Azure (green) matches the Site name from publish settings.